# clearpage with appendices

Tags: appendices, undefined, clearpage

I am compiling my dissertation chapters. When I wrote a chapter in a standalone Latex file, the file did compile without any error. However, when I copied the text body from the standalone to an "input" file, I get the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\clear@ppage ->\if@openright
\cleardoublepage \else \clearpage \fi
l.103 \begin{appendices}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.
```

Here is a minimal example which reproduces this error:

```
%Codes in the main latex file
\documentclass[oneside,final, letterpaper]{ucr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix} %Package used to create appendix

\begin{document}
\input{chapter1}
\end{document}

%Codes in the inputted file "chapter1"
\section{Intro}

\lipsum

\begin{appendices}
1. It shows error.
\end{appendices}
```

I will appreciate if someone could guide me here.

Comment: Well, the code you've not shared uses `\if@openright` but never defines it. This occurs around line 103, when you use `\begin{appendices}`. So either make sure it is defined or don't use anything which uses it. If you want help with diagnosis, we need code for a MNWE which produces that error when compiled. Otherwise, all anybody can do is tell you what the error message says, which you hopefully already read.

Comment: @cfr I apologize for my shoddiness here. I basically used the following codes:\clearpage \begin{appendices} some text \end{appendices}. I am not sure where \if@openright appears from.

Comment: That's why you need to provide code for a minimal document which reproduces the error. If you can't tell which part of your code is responsible, even with the code, how should we guess, without it?

Comment: @cfr Ok, I have edited my original post and now it includes a minimal example reproducing the error.

Comment: Can you get the error if you change `ucr` to `book`, say? If not, where can we get `ucr.cls`?

Comment: No, the error does not seem to occur with `book`. `ucr.cls` is my university's latex template. It can be obtained by downloading **LaTex Template (chairperson)** from: (http://graduate.ucr.edu/forms/ucr%20phd%20thesis%20latex%20template%20OneChair2017.zip)

Comment: When you compiled the chapter on its own, were you also using the `ucr` class? Or did you use some other class there? That is, you must have had a `\documentclass` etc. in `chapter1.tex` to compile it on its own. Also, I recommend adding that link to your question.

Comment: But, please, don't link directly to the `.zip`. Some of us are quite suspicious of such links :). Link to the page where the university provides the download.

Comment: You are right, it worked with the `article` class. Here is the link to the university's download page: http://graduate.ucr.edu/filingresources.html

Comment: Thanks. Was just going to put http://graduate.ucr.edu/filingresources.html :-).

Comment: The `appendix` package is incompatible with the class. `appendix` expects `\if@openright` to be defined, as it would be by `book` or `report`, for example. But `ucr` does not provide this - possibly because you don't have a choice about this aspect of the document. What do you need the `appendix` package for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `ucr` is incompatible with the package `appendix`. However, the class supports the inclusion of appendices in the table of contents, with their page numbers. I'm not sure what you want the `appendix` package for, but you don't need it for those features, at least. Rather than the `appendices` environment, just use `\appendix` as shown in the sample `appendix.tex`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-ch1.tex}
\chapter{Intro}

\lipsum
\appendix
\chapter{Aardvark Appendectomies 1456/1567}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item This appendix will be added to the table of contents, together with its page number.
  \item No package is necessary.
  \item No error is thrown.
\end{enumerate}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[oneside,final, letterpaper]{ucr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\input{\jobname-ch1}
\end{document}
```

[image: introduction and appendix]

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. This is useful.